# How to retrieve data object to the user without copying the data and without exposing the pointer?

Tags: c++, oop, data-structures

I'm trying to build a class that holds a data structure that contains my data objects inside of it.

The user can use a function in my class to retrieve one of this objects (by the object key).

Can I do it without copying the object to the return object and without return the pointer (so the user can't update my data)?

I don't care to wrap or change my data object to solve this problem.

To make it simple I wrote an array with CData simple object, Here is my code:

```
class CData
{
public:
    CData() {};
    virtual ~CData() {};
    
    CString m_sID;
    CString m_sName;
};

class CMyDataContainer
{
public:
    CMyDataContainer() {};
    virtual ~CMyDataContainer() {};

    CData GetDataByID(CString sID);
    void AddData() {};

private:
    CData ArrAllData[1000];
};

CData CMyDataContainer::GetDataByID(CString sID)
{
    CData EmptyDataToRetrive;

    // Find the data object
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
    {
        if (ArrAllData[i].m_sID == sID)
        {
            // Copying the object I've found to a new object
            // Can I avoid this copy and return the user an object he can use but dont change
            // My original object?
            return ArrAllData[i];
        }
    }

    return EmptyDataToRetrive;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Return a const reference:

```
const CData& CMyDataContainer::GetDataByID(CString sID)
```

that is the right semantic to indicate your user shouldn't modify it.